# Please help me to show analytically that for A $\subseteq$ Ω, the following collection of sets F ={∅,Ω,A,Ac}, is a sigma-algebra of subsets of Ω.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Please help me to show analytically that for $A\subseteq Ω$, the following collection of sets $F =\{\emptyset,\Omega,A,A^c\}$,
is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$.

this is the first time trying this so please help me. I'm really struggling with this matter.

I`m not sure about the tag

Answer (score 3):

A $\sigma$ algebra $F$ of subsets of $\Omega$ fulfills the following 4 conditions:

1) $\Omega \in F$ (this is fulfilled by your definition of F)

2) $X \in F \implies X^c \in F$ (which is also trivially fulfilled by your definition)

3) $(X_n: n \in \mathbb{N}) \in F \implies \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} X_n \in F$ (this is also fulfilled as the only subsets aside from $\Omega$ and $\emptyset$ is the disjoint pair of $A, A^c$).

4) Finite intersections which is implied by (3).

And so, $F$ is a $\sigma$ algebra of subsets of $\Omega$.

Comment: Could anyone confirm?

Comment: You should be able to confirm on your own; nothing here is more complicated than simply stating the definitions.